# C++ Smart Pointers erroring

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

So I tried getting around the smart pointer, but I just can't get it working!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>> s;
    s->push(14);
    s->push(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < s->size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << s->front();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << s->back();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    Sleep(1500);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I mistakely deleted your comment. Well, I did std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>> s = new std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>>();  ,and it didn't work. But it works with your option, std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>> s = std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>>();, Thank you!

Comment: `>> But it works with your option, std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>> s = std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>>();` No it doesn't! Please pay attention to the use of `std::make_unique` in the JHBonarius's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `<memory>` include in your header. Then you are creating a pointer, but no object where it's pointing to. Try

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <queue> // std::queue
#include <Windows.h> // Sleep
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr & std::make_unique

int main()
{
    // next line returns an std::unique_ptr<std::queue<int>>, hence the 'auto'
    auto s = std::make_unique<std::queue<int>>();
    s->push(14);
    s->push(2);

    std::cout << s->front() << "\n";
    std::cout << s->back() << "\n";

    Sleep(1500);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/FLBMX9359)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. So, make_unique is used for creating smart pointers then?

Comment: @CroampaDanielNestiutorul not fully true, `std::make_unique` is a way to make a `std::unique_ptr` a unique pointer. There's also a `std::shared_ptr`, which is not unique. You can also use `std::unique_prt::reset` to create a unique pointer from an existing pointer.

Comment: But then, what is the difference between an unique pointer and a shared pointer?

Comment: @CroampaDanielNestiutorul a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is unique: other pointers may not copy it. A [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) can be copied. With "copied" I mean: point to the same address. <-- you can click the names to go to cpp reference. com